# W-types and inverse image functor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, topos-theory, type-theory

Since the question did not get an answer here I have posted it to mathoverflow at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218855/w-types-and-inverse-image-functor

All sheaf topoi have [W-types](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/W-type) and in fact there's an explicit construction given by [Benno van den Berg & Ieke Moerdijk](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/ast/Papers/vdBM_Wtypes.pdf), but the construction is quite involved.

I would like to know whether the inverse image part of a geometric morphism always preserves W-types for more general reasons or pointers to references detailing the conditions on functors so they preserve W-types.

Inverse image functors always preserve the natural numbers object, which is a particular kind of W-type, but the proof of this fact is very specific to the NNO so this might suggest that they don't all preserve W-types, but I have not found anything about this stated anywhere.

Comment: Initial algebras for the simplest polynomial endofunctors (i.e. those of the form $X \mapsto A_0 + A_1 \times X + A_2 \times X^2 + \cdots + A_n \times X^n$) can be constructed using only colimits and finite products, so they are preserved by any inverse image functor. But I imagine there are difficulties for the general case, because inverse image functors don't usually preserve exponential objects – so it's not even clear whether algebras get mapped to algebras.

Comment: @NiftyKitty95 You should not change "toposes" to "topoi". Let the writer decide.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yeah, I agree here. It was just my last attempt to get a response before the bounty expires.

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too.  Since it didn't get any answers here, how about asking on MathOverflow?

Comment: @MikeShulman I have a partial answer to the question which was sufficient for my needs at the time. The inverse image of a locally connected geometric morphism will always preserve W types. This includes the constant presheaf functors $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}^P$ for a poset $P$ with a least element which was the concrete case I was interested in at the time.

Comment: @AlešBizjak Where can I find a proof of that special case?

Comment: @MikeShulman I have added an outline of the argument as an answer below. I hope that helps you, but as you can see it is not a very interesting proof.

Comment: @AlešBizjak Thanks!  I may go ahead and ask the general question again on MO, if you don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: @MikeShulman I have asked the question at mathoverflow. The link is  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218855/w-types-and-inverse-image-functor. What do I do with the question here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I did not get the answer and I have asked the same question at mathoverflow now.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the references. I deleted my answer since it contained mistakes.

Comment: @AlešBizjak Whatever happens with the question, the link to the MO copy should be more prominently visible. So perhaps you could put it into your question. For some advice what to do in situations like this you might have a look on meta. For example, there is this post: [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9210) And also this one: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085) (And many other discussions on meta.)